# Stream stdio to a website (like buildbot)

Tags: python, django, stdio

So I am trying to work in a stdio stream for a webapp similar to Buildbot. Does anyone know how Buildbot deals with stdio? It is streaming (so it seems) and that would be exactly what I need for this program.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Python with Django by the way

Answer (score 0):

Buildbot uses [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which has a rather different programming style from Django.

I'd say you'd have to write a service in Twisted to do what you're after. Communicate with it from Django and have it do the streaming part you need.

*(In Django, as most web apps, you have one thread/call per request that blocks on db/io calls. In Twisted, you defer async function calls to the library and have callbacks to continue once the io is done. It feel a bit wierd at first, but it's actually quite nice, especially for apps that aren't just web-servers.)*

Answer (score 0):

Django allows you to return iterators from views. You could return an iterator that incrementally reads the stream and yields it back to django.
[request-response/#passing-iterators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators)
[ex. snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/)

Here is the simplest possible solution

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser) #SECURE THIS SHIT
def stdout_cmd(request, command):
              #buffsize=1 reads a char at a time
    process = Popen(command, shell=True, buffsize='1', stdout=PIPE)
              # FileWrapper creates an iterator class for stdout
    wrapper = FileWrapper(process.stdout)
              # text/plain causes monospaced output in browser
    return HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
```

As long as you can create a file-like object you can wrap it in FileWrapper.
Be aware that if output of you shell is sporadic, you will want to create your own iterator that reads a line at a time e.g.

```
wrapper = (line for line in process.stdout) # brackets create an iterator object
```

NOTE: This will consume worker threads and block people connecting to your server if you have too many concurrent long-poll pages loading. considder using gevent/greenlets. for high-traffic environments.